# Content and structure: moving files completely destroys destination library columns?

Tags: 2010, content-and-structure

Wanted to be sure that this is 'by design' and not a bug of my version (2010).

If I have a source library and a destination library, the first one being plain and normal and the second one having 2 mandatory metadata columns, moving the files completely 'erases' the 2 metadata columns of the destination library.

They are not completely cancelled, just they do not show up when uploading new files or editing the newly pasted in ones. If I look at edit properties, the 2 columns are not there.

Is this normal behaviour of moving via Content and structure? (I have been using it because I wanted to retain versioning and created by/modified by)

Comment: Are the columns in 2 defined by another ContentType which is not the default ContentType?

Comment: I have left the content type as default in the document library. If I am not mistaken when you create a brand new dl the content type is document but the settings say 'use content type: no'. I have tried to switch it to yes but the columns were not shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is by design unfortunately and has caused us some headaches over time. When you use content and structure to move or copy files, it updates the destination list with the columns from the source list so the metadata persists.

In some instances, we had to go back into the list settings and rebind columns to content types because they got broken or replace with a column from the source.